# How can I get all keys from Map at typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I use `Angular 2`. Also I have `StatisticsService` which has this method:

```
getComingStatistics(): Promise<Map<String, number>> {
    const url = `${this.eventUrl}/rest/report/statistic/coming`;
    return this.http.get(url)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => {

            return response.json().data as Map<String, number>
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

I make this call from a component:

```
constructor(private statisticsService: StatisticsService) {}

comingStatistics: Map<String, number>;
allComingUsers: number;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.statisticsService.getComingStatistics().then(comingStatistics => {
        console.log(comingStatistics);
        console.log(comingStatistics.values());
    });
}
```

The problem is in this line `console.log(comingStatistics.values());`. I have this exception: `Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: comingStatistics.values is not a function`.

Also no one of the map's method works (like `keys()`, `forEach`, etc.). There is only one way to get a value: `comingStatistics['someKey']`.

How can I get all keys and values of my map ?

Comment: Make sure you assign the value to a local variable before trying to access the map.

Comment: Then try .get(property), where "property" is the name of the value you are trying to retrieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type assertion cheats type system to consider the result a map with

```
return response.json().data as Map<String, number>
```

But it doesn't make `data` object a map.

It should be converted to `Map` in order to be a map:

```
return new Map(Object.entries(response.json().data));
```

Comment: I get this error:  `property entries does not exist on type 'ObjectContructor'`

Comment: It is ES2017 method. You need TypeScript to be configured properly, there should be `es2017` in `lib` section, also respective polyfill should be loaded.

Comment: Thanks! But now I get `Property 'json' does not exist on type '{}'`. What is it ?

Comment: That's because response is untyped. Use `response: Response`.

Comment: The proper place is where the variable is defined. `.then(response: Resonse) => { ...`.